# SWIG - How to wrap to python a class with a constructor that takes a 'const double*'

Tags: python, c++, pointers, swig

I have to wrap a vector (geometric vector) class from C++ to Python using Swig.
One of the constructors of this `Vector3` class accept a `const double*`:

```
Vector3(const double* list);
```

I'd like to wrap it so that I can do this in Python:

```
vec = Vector3([1, 2, 3])
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145385/discussion-between-flexo-and-dan-niero).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend changing the prototype to

```
Vector(const double* list, size_t len);
```

A full example supporting construction using

```
import example
v = example.Vector([1.0,2.0,3.0])
```

example.h

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdlib>

class Vector {
 public:
  Vector();
  Vector(double x, double y, double z);
  Vector(const double* list, size_t len);
};
```

example.cpp

```
#include "example.h"
#include <iostream>

Vector::Vector() {
  std::cout << "Vector()" << std::endl;
}

Vector::Vector(double x, double y, double z) {
  std::cout << "Vector(double, double, double)" << std::endl;
}

Vector::Vector(const double* list, size_t len) {
  std::cout << "Vector(const double*)" << std::endl;
}
```

example.i

```
%module example
%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "example.h"
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init {
  import_array();
}

%apply (double* IN_ARRAY1, size_t DIM1)         \
{(const double* list, size_t len)}

%include "example.h"
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name="example",
      py_modules=['example'],
      ext_modules=[Extension("_example",
                     ["example.i","example.cpp"],
                     swig_opts=['-c++'],
                  )])
```

Comment: If you want, you can look into `numpy.i` and hardcode the length argument, but really recommend not doing this

Comment: Unfortunately there are two problems:
1 - I can't change the c++ code, it's not ours.
2 - I can't use numpy. We have to make the python code run in a software called Maya (for 3d computer animation and fx). Because of some shortsighted development on their side, certain python libraries like numpy cannot be compiled against the python they embedded in their software.

Anyway, I thank you for your detailed answer, if nobody will reply with one that I can you I will certainly accept yours.

Comment: @DanNiero: that's an important constraint; please include that in your question.

Comment: @DanNiero Thank you. I guess a reason for very little replies is the fact that the prototype `Vector(const double*)` is very unfortunate. What you can do is copy the functionality from `numpy.i` for the `IN_ARRAY1`macro and hardcode the length. The code in `numpy.i` accepts list arguments and not just 'NumPy' arrays. Basically what Mark did in the other answer

Comment: @Jens Munk Thanks I will try.

I understand that it's a "bad case" but I was very curious to find out if somebody else did find a reasonable way make it work. For me a "no, it's impossible with this specific constructor" it is a perfectly acceptable answer (if it is explained why, that is).

Comment: It is possible - modify `numpy.i` for `IN_ARRAY1` to use a fixed lenght of say 3 - I did that the other day, but the typemap is using a bunch of macros and it was not easy to paste this solution. The reason for it is bad is because looking at the interface there is no way to tell what the length of the array is

Answer (score 4):

You can write a specific input typemap for `const double* list`.  Note this example has no error checking for brevity and includes an inline class for test purposes:

```
%module test

%include <windows.i>

%typemap(in) const double* list (double value[3]) %{
    for(Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        value[i] = PyFloat_AsDouble(PySequence_GetItem($input, i));
    $1 = value;
%}

%inline %{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class __declspec(dllexport) Vector3
{
    public:
        Vector3(const double* list)
        {
            cout << list[0] << ',' << list[1] << ',' << list[2] << endl;
        }
};
%}
```

Output:

> ```
> >>> import test
> >>> v = test.Vector3([1.1,2.2,3.3])
> 1.1,2.2,3.3
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately this throw the following error:

NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Vector3'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    gmath::Vector3::Vector3()
    gmath::Vector3::Vector3(double,double,double)
    gmath::Vector3::Vector3(gmath::Vector3 const &)
    gmath::Vector3::Vector3(double const *)

I too thougth this should work, but it doesn't for a constructor, while it seems to work for a normal method...

Comment: Actually I tried and it doesn't work on a method neither. my mistake saying it did before

Comment: It does work as I compiled my test case and that's how I generated the output, but without more information on your specific class it's difficult to say what is wrong with your application of the technique.

Comment: The error message implies the typemap wasn't applied. As written above the typemap will only work if the parameter name is `list`. Make sure the parameter name matches the one used on the const double* constructor, or remove it to generically use the typemap on all const double parameters.

Comment: off course I have been careful about the parameter list, but there is nothing that made this solution works for me. I'm not saying you are wrong, just that at this point I suspect it is something else (compiler?) because on principle what you wrote make a lot of sense to me...

Comment: @DanNiero Can you provide the whole header file definition of `Vector3`? Also, are you on Windows or something else?  What compiler?  Also, show your `.i` file attempt.  There's really not enough information to solve your problem.